# How to disable/enable backorder for particular website/store?

Tags: magento2, cataloginventory, backorder

I want to enable/disable backorder from one of the available websites. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This is default Magento 2 behaviour and as we can see in screen-shot Backorder has 'global' scope so we can't change on store/website level.

[image]

Comment: That I know, that's why I created this thread. Is there any workaround to make it work on store/website level?

Answer (score 0):

yes there's a way...check the following link:

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/allow-backorders-website-scope/